# entering localhost leads to yahoo search engine

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I have wamp installed, suddenly it became infected as it seems, every time I enter localhost and press enter it takes me to a default-search engine and then yahoo which says it cannot find the page, I have also reset firefox but the problem persists, how can I block this search engine redirector

Obviously it is a browser hijacker, now I am running full scan with kasperskey, also now downloading malwarebytes

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try scanning with [AdwCleaner](https://toolslib.net/downloads/viewdownload/1-adwcleaner/).

> AdwCleaner is a free removal tool for :
>
> - Adware (ads softwares)
> - PUP/LPI (Potentially Undesirable Program)
> - Toolbars
> - Hijacker (Hijack of the browser's homepage)

Comment: Thank You Very Much, resolved by deleting some new programs installed from the control panel

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved by going to control panel and uninstalling  latest programs, I do not think it would be correct to mention which, because there were more than one, and I don't know for sure which one,